# How do I solve the Excel sumproduct formula to get weeknumbers from dates working

Tags: excel, sumproduct

An Excel question.

I got a table with a column of dates and a calculated column with value's. In a summary cell I do have

```
  =SOMPRODUCT( (MONTH(Tijd[Datum(s)])=MONTH(TODAY()) )* (Tijd[Uren gewerkt in decimalen]) )
```

of course works perfect. However with the same columns and calculating the weekly based summary I get error's

```
  =SOMPRODUCT( (WEEKNUMBER(Tijd[Datum(s)])=WEEKNUMBER(TODAY()) ) * (Tijd[Uren gewerkt in decimalen]) )
```

This gives me a #Value err.
If I use WeekNumber(AnEmptyCell) as an test, it just returns a zero, no err value.

F9 key results -

```
Tijd[Datum(s)] - all the dates and zero's when no date.

(WEEKNUMMER(Tijd[Datum(s)]) - #Value error
```

all the other parts are also okay.

All the fields in the Datums Column are date fields.

What do I wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: It was easier to answer the question if you used English formulas. You can get it if you select the target cell, press Alt + F11, Ctrl + G and write the following VBA command: ? ActiveCell.Formula

Comment: Nice tip, However for on the Mac you have to use the 'Fn' + 'Alt' + 'F11' . Then the Ctrl + CMD + G. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of Excel formula functions: those that can be used with arrays and those that cannot. `MONTH` is of the first type, `WEEKNUM` is of the second. To test it, put two arbitrary dates into A1:A2, and enter `=MONTH(A1:A2)` into B1:B2 (Select B1:B2, and press Ctrl + Shift + Enter), and `=WEEKNUM(A1:A2)` into C1:C2. The first will show valid values but the second will be two `#VALUE!` errors.

If you use the formula in the above setup, I would recommend, to examine if the date is after the Monday and before the Sunday of the given week.

I don't have access to an Excel with Dutch (?) locale, so I added the English name of the functions to insert in your formula:

```
  =SOMPRODUCT( ( TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1 <= Tijd[Datum(s)] ) * ( Tijd[Datum(s)] < TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+7 ) * (Tijd[Uren gewerkt in decimalen]) )
```

Comment: Hi thank you, I did use somewhere else already an extra column with week numbers, So I have to use it, the extra column here too. I do understand your formula and save it for later.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

```
WeekNummer() or:
WeekNumber() or:
WeekNum()?
```

(The function's name is locale dependent)